# SQL - Get from last reoccurring status

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table like below

```
#ID ResultStatus    StatusDate
100 F               9/01/2017
100 S               6/01/2017
100 F               2/01/2017
300 F               7/01/2017
300 F               3/01/2017
300 S               1/01/2017
500 S               7/01/2017
800 F               7/01/2017
800 S               3/01/2017
800 F               2/01/2017
800 S               1/01/2017
```

I want to get all the 'F' records after the last 'S' record.
It should just return

- For ID 100 the 9/01/2017 record
- For ID 300 the 3/01/2017 and 7/01/2017 records
- For ID 500 nothing since there is no F
- For ID 800 the 7/01/2017 record

  Selecting all the failures after the last success.

I am using Teradata SQL but any SQL help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard SQL method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.resultstatus = 'F' and
      t.statusdate > (select max(t2.statusdate)
                      from t t2
                      where t2.resultstatus = 'S' and t2.id = t.id
                     );
```

However, I would also be inclined to do this using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when t.resultstatus = 'S' then statusdate end) over (partition by id) as max_s
      from t
     ) t
where t.resultstatus = 'F' and
      t.statusdate > max_s;
```

If you want all rows when there is no `S`, then change the `where` to:

```
where resultstatus = 'F' and
      (statusdate > max_s or max_s is null);
```

EDIT:

The following may work as well:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify t.resultstatus = 'F' and
        t.statusdate > max(case when t.resultstatus = 'S' then statusdate end) over (partition by id);
```

Comment: Teradata supports a QUALIFY clause, which behaves like a HAVING clause  does for aggregate functions. So I think you could get away with `QUALIFY t.statusdate > {window aggregate} ` as a replacement for `t.statusdate > max_s`.

Comment: @RobPaller . . . That may be a good suggestion.  If you filter on `resultstatus` in the `qualify`, then I assume it does not affect the window function.  This situation is tricky, because of the filtering on different statuses.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. After looking at the code I was like why did I not think of that :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

By using CROSS JOIN, Analytic function ROW_NUMBER() we can accomplish this problem. Here is the SQL solution at the below link that would explain it in detail.

DDL :-

```
CREATE TABLE Sample( ID INT, ResultStatus VARCHAR(10), StatusDate DATE);

INSERT INTO Sample VALUES(100,'F','09-01-2017');
INSERT INTO Sample VALUES(100,'S','06-01-2017');
INSERT INTO Sample VALUES(100,'F','02-01-2017');

INSERT INTO Sample VALUES(300,'F','07-01-2017');
INSERT INTO Sample VALUES(300,'F','03-01-2017');
INSERT INTO Sample VALUES(300,'S','01-01-2017');

INSERT INTO Sample VALUES(500,'F','07-01-2017');

INSERT INTO Sample VALUES(800,'F','07-01-2017');
INSERT INTO Sample VALUES(800,'S','03-01-2017');
INSERT INTO Sample VALUES(800,'F','02-01-2017');
INSERT INTO Sample VALUES(800,'S','01-01-2017');
```

SQL :-

```
SELECT B.id,B.ResultStatus,B.StatusDate
  FROM
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StatusDate DESC ) AS rn,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ResultStatus DESC,StatusDate ) AS rn_status
  FROM Sample ) A
  CROSS JOIN
 (
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StatusDate DESC ) AS rn,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ResultStatus DESC,StatusDate DESC ) AS rn_status
  FROM Sample 
 ) B
WHERE A.ResultStatus = 'S'
  AND A.ResultStatus != B.ResultStatus
  AND B.StatusDate > A.StatusDate 
  AND A.ID = B.ID
  AND A.rn > B.rn
  AND A.rn_status = 1
  AND B.rn_status - B.rn = 1 
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2d17/17

Comment: Thanks @Teja for your help!